# Ladies Western Flyer

Tags: brakes, pedals, saddle

I have a great vintage Western Flyer, Ladies bike, that I am trying to find a few parts for. I need to replace the rear Altenburger Synchron brake and I want to replace the seat and pedals back to something original. I can't even figure out where to find parts. This is a great bike and I want to get it back to as close to original as I can.

Comment: What's the question here? Are you just looking for a place to get parts?

Answer (score 1):

I know there are a few web pages devoted to the Western Auto bikes, if you look around.  That would probably be the best place to ask.